# Submersion with contractible fibers

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homotopy-theory

Let $f: M\to N$ be a surjective submersion of manifolds with contractible fibers. Is it true that $M$ and $N$ are homotopy equivalent?

Comment: If $f$ is proper then, as a surjective submersion, it is a fibration, and in this case it is true that it is a homotopy equivalence under the assumption on its fibres. On the other hand it is not true that every surjective submersion is proper, and there are surjective submersions which are not fibrations.

Comment: @Tyrone: Surprisingly, in this setting $f$ is a homotopy equivalence. This is a rather nontrivial result due to Meigniez.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Surprisingly, your question has positive answer:

**Theorem 1.** Suppose that $f: M\to N$ is a surjective submersion with contractible fibers. Then $f$ is a fibration (in the sense of Serre). In particular, $f$ is a homotopy-equivalence.

See Corollary 13 in

G. Meigniez, Submersions, fibrations and bundles. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 354 (2002), no. 9, 3771–3787.

In fact, this result is proven under a weaker assumption, $f$ is only required  to be a "homotopy submersion".

**Remark.** In the same paper it is proven (Corollary 31)

**Theorem 2.** Suppose that $f: M\to N$ is a surjective submersion with fibers diffeomorphic to $R^p$ for some $p$. Then $f$ is a locally trivial (in $C^\infty$ category) fiber bundle.

However, you do not need this stronger conclusion.